# Pasting multi-line queries into BigQuery SQL shell

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running the BigQuery command line shell and I'm not able to successfully run multi-line queries (aka queries with line breaks) because whenever I paste the query into the shell each line gets run individually instead of the whole thing together.

For example,

```sql
select * from table
```

works fine because it is in one line but if I try to run

```sql
select
*
from
table
```

it does not work because each line gets run separately.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using the bq shell? You can execute multi line queries in the UI or by using `bq query  "select ......"`.

Comment: @ECris in case access to the table is enabled through service account, it cannot be accessed from UI. Also `bq query "select ......"` does not work for queries containing single quotes.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `query` command creates a query job that runs the supplied SQL query. in the documentation [Using the bq command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#general_usage) you can find some examples like:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
'SELECT
   COUNT(*)
 FROM
   `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare'
```

Comment: That's from command line, not in bq shell. I've still not found a way to do a multi-line query in the bq shell.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I too couldn't find decent help on this, so I created a bit of a workaround using the CONCAT function. Notice that I have a space before the FROM clause. Hope his helps.

DECLARE table_name STRING DEFAULT '20220214';
DECLARE query STRING;

```
SET query = CONCAT("""select user_pseudo_id, user_id""",
""" FROM `app.analytics.events_""" || table_name || """` where user_id IS NOT NULL group by user_pseudo_id, user_id""");

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
```